# What type of options apply to the SlugField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, field

If we see the documentation of Django, we see this;

> ```
> SlugField
>
> class SlugField(max_length=50, **options)
> ```

`**options` : is a kwargs but Django doesn't show me anything about of what other parameter I can use it.

I appreciate if somebody help me.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Comment: These are the options that are applied to a `CharField`, and by extent a `Field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: these are options you can pass to a [**`CharField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField), and by extent a [**`Field`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field).

A `SlugField` is a class that extends the `CharField` class, we can see this in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2023):

> ```
> class SlugField(CharField):
>     default_validators = [validators.validate_slug]
>     description = _("Slug (up to %(max_length)s)")
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, max_length=50, db_index=True, allow_unicode=False, **kwargs):
>         self.allow_unicode = allow_unicode
>         if self.allow_unicode:
>             self.default_validators = [validators.validate_unicode_slug]
>         super().__init__(*args, max_length=max_length, db_index=db_index, **kwargs)
>
>     #...
> ```

So it sets `max_length` by default to `50`, `db_index` to `True` and `allow_unicode` to `False`, and passes all the positional and named arguments to the super constructor (the one of the `CharField`.

The `CharField` class passes the arguments to its super constructor as well, according to the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1033):

> ```
> class CharField(Field):
>     description = _("String (up to %(max_length)s)")
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(self.max_length))
> ```

So that means that it comes down to the [options one can pass to *any* `Field` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options). For example: `db_column`, `default`, `editable`, `help_text`, etc.